# Allow to add configurable product without selecting attribute

Tags: magento, php

I have set up a few config products with the options to change the colour. At the moment I have a table which shows all the options so you can add more than one option at once but It is also showing colour swatchs which are shown by the attribute.

The problem is that if a colour swatch is not clicked then you can't add to cart, so I need some way of making Magento allow users to add to cart without selecting the attribute.

I have changed the attribute colour to Values Required: No but this hasn't fixed the issue?

Comment: It seems like you would better ask - how to pre-select the attribute Colour option, if I understand you correctly. Because adding configurable product to the cart without selected option makes no sense.

Comment: @SlayerBirden This is because I am using two modules which both display the attributes but obviously we don't want the user to have to select the option twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to pre-select an attribute option as @slayer-birden suggested, there is an extension which allow us to select a default option when we configure the associated products - [set preconfigured values on product edit page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/set-preconfigured-values-on-product-edit-page-9945.html)

I didn't personaly tried it yet, but looks like it will do the trick.